# Do natural structures generate above 128 blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

We are running a Minecraft server (bukkit) with new version 1.2. The height limit was doubled in the release, but I can't find any natural structures that use the new space above 128 blocks. I found some jungle trees and mountains that are 122 blocks height, but nothing above 128.

Does the map generator generate natural structures higher than the old 128 block limit?

**Edit:**

A source for your answer would be nice. (The code of the part of the generator that limits the height, or a seed to proof structures above 128 blocks)

Comment: I forgot about that change. Maybe Notch will finally give us deeper oceans!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dinnerbone has [answered this question on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/s0pqt/i_am_nathan_adams_aka_dinnerbone_developer_of/c4a5y98):

> #### Will the terrain generator ever be updated to use the full 256 blocks of build height?
>
> It's intentionally designed to only go as high as it does right now. Maybe in the future, or with different generators/options, but right now we're happy with the extra breathing room for players.

Answer (score 2):

No, natural structures will not generate any differently as part of the height limit change. This change is thanks to the conversion to the new file format, Anvil, which supports layers 0-255 (as opposed to the Region file format, which only supports layers 0-127). The terrain generator works just like it used to, and blocks between layers 128-255 just default to air.

Comment: a source would be nice.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that if you added a source, the upvotes for Walter's comment would magically spawn some upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't generate terrain above 128 just like the old terrain generation everthing above there is just air, but if you want there's a mod that changes this, all it does is change a few numbers in the terrain generation code the rest stays the same, I'm pretty sure its called Dynamic Heights Mod (or something along those lines).